# Load child nodes without expand in ExtJs Tree Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have created a tree using Treepanel in Extjs. The following is the code snippet which is used which to traverse the node using drag and drop

```
beforenodedrop:function(dropEvent){
                        try {

                            targetNode = dropEvent.target;
                            sourceNode = dropEvent.dropNode;
                            sourceNode = getDeepAllChildNodes(sourceNode);
                            treeTarget = sourceNode.getOwnerTree().id;

                            if (treeTarget == 'tree' && sourceNode.attributes.lvl > 0){

                                changeAlignTrees = true;

                                if (sourceNode.childNodes != null){
                                    var targetFather = {};
                                    var node = sourceNode;
                                    if(targetNode.id==-2){
                                        targetFather = targetNode;
                                    }else{
                                        targetFather = targetNode.parentNode;
                                    }
                                    while(sourceNode.hasChildNodes() == true){
                                        node = node.firstChild;
                                        if (node.hasChildNodes() == false){
                                            node = node.parentNode;
                                            targetFather.appendChild(node.firstChild);
                                            if(node.hasChildNodes() == false){
                                                node = node.parentNode;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                if(targetNode.id==-2){
                                    dropEvent.point = 'append';
                                }else{
                                    dropEvent.point = 'below';
                                    targetNode.leaf='true';
                                }

                                Ext.Ajax.request({
                                    url: "testURL",

                                    params: {
                                        option: 'alUnit',
                                        unitNum: sourceNode.id,
                                        parentUnitNum: '-1'
                                    },
                                    scriptTag: true,
                                    success: function(response, options){

                                    }
                                });
                            }else{
                                dropEvent.cancel=true;  
                            }
                        }catch (e) {
                            logException("Exception: " + e.description);
                        }
                    }
```

This is Async Tree Node, if i do not expand the nodes then the following line `node = node.firstChild;` returns null. I have one more function to get all the child nodes, the following is the code snippet

```
 getDeepAllChildNodes = function(node){ 
                    var allNodes = new Array(); 
                    if(!Ext.value(node,false)){ 
                            return []; 
                    } 

                    if(!node.hasChildNodes()){ 
                            return node; 
                    }else{ 
                            allNodes.push(node); 
                            node.eachChild(function(Mynode){allNodes = allNodes.concat(getDeepAllChildNodes(Mynode));});         
                    } 
                    return allNodes; 
            };
```

When executed the line `!node.hasChildNodes()` the following error `"Object doesn't support property or method 'hasChildNodes'"`
How can i achieve traversing all child nodes in treepanel without expanding.

Comment: Please provide the definition of your tree and the store behind it, as well as your ExtJS version.

Comment: Tree definition  `loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
                  baseAttrs: { uiProvider: Ext.tree.TreeNotIconsUI }  }),` and ExtJS Version `4.0.7`

I also tried `preloadChildren:true` & `preLoad()` as well. Did not help